# Why would a String fail to be encoded in the default charset?

Tags: java, byte, encode

The documentation for `getBytes` for the `String` class is as follow:

> Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset, storing the result into a new byte array.
>
> The behavior of this method when this string cannot be encoded in the default charset is unspecified. The java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder class should be used when more control over the encoding process is required.

What I don't get is in what cases would it fail? In my mind it is just a sequence of bytes.

Answer (score 3):

The contents of the String might include characters which are not able to be represented in the default charset.

---

Suppose the default charset we are targeting does not support, say, Chinese characters.

You can override the default charset with a JVM property to test this.

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

This

```
System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("学中文".getBytes()));
```

Prints

```
UTF-8
[-61, -91, -62, -83, -62, -90, -61, -92, -62, -72, -62, -83, -61, -90, -30, -128, -109, -30, -128, -95]
```

Looks broadly correct.

If I do the same for

```
-Dfile.encoding=US-ASCII
```

The result is

```
US-ASCII
[63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63]
```

So it seems the unspecified behaviour in this case is to print the `?` character, which is  what 63 is in ASCII.

Comment: The result in ASCII will be the unicode replacement character � turned into a regular `?` since ASCII can't represent the *unicode* replacement character. The default encoding shouldn't be touched, and the application should always use a specific encoding instead of trusting the default.